# Orbeon Forms: Inhibit Data Entry after Form is Completed

Tags: orbeon

Sorry for the basic question... I'm relatively new to Orbeon Forms..

Is it possible to inhibit the change of a form (to most users) once the has been submitted and the status has reached the "Completed" ?

Specific business key users must be able to change these forms if required (like Admin rights).

At present anyone with the right permissions can re-open a form and change the data..

Many thanks

PeteA

Comment: Did you read doc? There are a lot of information about permissions.
https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control
https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control/owner-group
And it depends of with version of Orbeon you have, CE vs PE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is the following:

1. In the process that runs when users submit the form, use the `set-workflow-stage(name = "…")` action to change the workflow stage to something like `submitted`.
2. In Form Builder, set the entire form to be readonly if the workflow stage is `submitted` using a formula like `fr:workflow-stage-value() = 'submitted'`.

You can find more about it in [this blog post](https://blog.orbeon.com/2021/01/new-workflow-capabilities-in-orbeon.html).

Comment: Thanks avernet,

Do you have a working example I could look at?

PeteA

Comment: Unfortunately this "workflow" option isnt available to us yet..

Are there any other options?

Comment: Mmh… is it because this relies on support for this feature being present in the implementation of the persistence API, and that the implementation in SAP Commerce doesn't support this yet? If so you could use a Hidden Field to store the workflow stage, naming it, say, `workflow-stage`. Then instead of calling the action `set-workflow-stage(name = "…")`, you would do `xf:setvalue(ref = "//workflow-stage", value = "'submitted'")`, and instead of `fr:workflow-stage-value() = 'submitted'` you would say `$workflow-stage = 'submitted'`. You'll let me know if this would work for you. -Alex

Comment: Thanks Alex,

How do I automatically set the workflow-stage when the 'Completed" state is set on the form?

xf:setvalue(ref = "//workflow-stage", value = "'submitted'")

PeteA

Comment: @PeteAtkin Are you asking where you should put that `xf:setvalue()` action? If so, it goes in the process that you're running when users submit data. That process is defined in your `properties-local.xml`. Does this help?

Comment: Alex, when the workflow-stage is set to "submitted" (i.e the user has pressed the SUBMIT button) we want to automatically trigger an event (via an action??) to set this new field value to, say "LOCKED". Then we can read this value in a formula to make the whole form read-only.

Comment: @PeteAtkin Got it: this is done with a `xf:setvalue()`, from a process, which is in your `properties-local.xml`. Are you already familiar with processes? If not, you might want to check https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes, and let me know if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have access to the properties-local.xml file.
So I have done something very simple and made the form read-only when the workflow-state "submitted" has been reached. The user then needs to press the SAVE PROGRESS button to move the state back to "updated" and the fields are open for entry again..